# Python List manipulation - couting common instances

Tags: python, list

I have a ListA = [1,2,3,3,2,1,3,3,1,3]

The 3s are in a sequence of 2,2,1 (2 instances, 2 instances, and 1 instance at the end)

I want to generate a ListB = [2,2,1] from the above ListA

I have code:

```
ls = [1,2,3,3,2,1,3,3,2,3]

pplist = []
pp = 0
for ii in range(0,len(ls)):
    if ls[ii] == 3:
        pp += 1
        
    else:
        if pp > 0:
            pplist.append(pp)
            pp = 0

print(pplist)
```

This gives me [2,2] and for the last element I have to add an additional if-loop.
Is there a way to achieve this without having additional code just for the last element?

(ListA could also end with multiple 3s instead of a single 3)

Thank you

R

Comment: you are *always* counting 3s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls = [1,2,3,3,2,1,3,3,2,3]

pplist = []
pp = 0
for ii in range(0,len(ls)):

    if ls[ii] == 3:
        pp += 1
        if ii == len(ls)-1:
            pplist.append(pp)
        
    else:
        if pp > 0:
            pplist.append(pp)
            pp = 0

print(pplist)
```

Answer (score 2):

there's a pretty easy way to do this with `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

nums = [1,2,3,3,2,1,3,3,2,3]
[sum(1 for _ in v) for k, v in groupby(nums) if k == 3]
# [2, 2, 1]
```

edit: adding a long form version of this to make it easier to understand:

```
def count_nums(nums, to_count=3):
    res = []
    for num, vals in groupby(nums):  # num is the number, vals is an iterable of the values in the group
        if num == to_count:
            num_vals = sum(1 for _ in vals)  # could also be `len(list(vals))`, i just don't want to create a whole list solely for its length
            res.append(num_vals)
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very concise. But it is very hard to follow for a beginner in Python!

Comment: i'll put a long version in so you can understand it better!